# $.ajax post to MVC controller returns Internal Server Error: Parameters dictionary contains null entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'appId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult CheckForInstaller(Int32)' in 'HLIT_TicketingMVC.Controllers.TicketController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

```
function SubmitAjax(url, message, successFunc, errorFunc) {
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:url,
    data:message,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:successFunc,
    error:errorFunc
  });
};
```

The data object is built as follows:

```
var message={"appId":application.val()};
```

I have also tried a jsonified string:

```
var message="{'appId':"+application.val()+"}";
```

and

```
var message="{'appId':'"+application.val()+"'}";
```

I validated that the message is coming through with a proper int value before it tries to post. The mouse over debugger most recently showed: `{appId="6"}`

The method signature on the controller is:

```
public ContentResult CheckForInstaller(int appId)
```

When I remove the parameter from the method signature, it does hit the breakpoint inside, so it's either the signature needing attributes of some kind, or the message isn't built properly I believe.

Comment: do you get any result when you're changing the int to a string:
public ContentResult CheckForInstaller(String appId) ?

Comment: What is that application object? Are you sure it works as expected?

Comment: @  çağdaş - yes when I mouse over the result, it shows the value I expect.
@ Pbirkoff - I didn't try that but found the problem, answer below accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove this:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

MVC isn't going to parse the JSON into an `int`. You want the default value of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: In such cases, do we have to define a special route for the action method that would be called? or is it automatically bound?

Comment: @LordCover: No, you don't need a special route. It's bound like any other form.

Answer (score 2):

I think it maybe that you are sending json to the controller try this

```
function SubmitAjax(url, message, successFunc, errorFunc) {
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:url,
    data:"appId=" + application.val(),//not sure where you get the value from in your current code  
    dataType: 'json',
    success:successFunc,
    error:errorFunc
  });
};
```

Comment: In such cases, do we have to define a special route for the action method that would be called? or is it automatically bound?