# $.ajax post to struts2 action returns Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am trying to perform this AJAX post  but getting a server 500 error. If I don't send any data i can see it hits break point set in the controller. But when I send data it doesnt and returns 500 error. help? Thanks.

In firebug console,
The request header has `Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`
and Response as `com.hearsay.example.mktpx.ui.action.LoadDefaultsAction.retrieveBenchmark()`

Code :

```
$.ajax( {
    type : "POST",
    url : "loadBenchMark",
    data : {'ruleset':'1'},
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("success"); 
        },
            error:error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error Thrown:"  +request.statusText); 
        }
 });
```

Action Class:

```
  public String retrieveBenchmark(int ruleset) {
    setBenchmarkProductList(retrieveBenchmarkProductList());
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="loadBenchMark"
        class="com.hearsay.example.mktpx.ui.action.LoadDefaultsAction" method="retrieveBenchmark">
   <result type="json"></result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the `ruleset` parameter from the method. Then, add an instance variable instead in the action class, with standard getter and setter methods - like this:

```
private int ruleset // or String, if you're passing String values

public int getRuleset() {
   return this.ruleset;
}

public void setRuleset(int ruleset) {
   this.ruleset = ruleset;
}
```

This is the way parameters are passed to a Struts action - Struts will call the appropriate setter. Remember to use correct data types - do not pass `String` values for `int` variables etc.

Comment: Thank you. My actual code has many ajax calls with different kinds of data (complex types). I am trying with a simple one to first get it working. I would like to know what mistake is in the code.

Comment: @silpa I clarified my answer again, perhaps it is more helpful now.

Comment: @Tommi It works this way. Thank you. I was looking at this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281808/ajax-post-to-mvc-controller-returns-internal-server-error-parameters-dictionar) and trying to get it working.