# How to write Struts2 action with dynamic method to accept call from jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I am struggling with a supposedly simple task. I have an ajax call to a method on action class. How should the action method look like? Thanks.

```
$.ajax( {
    type : "POST",
    url : "loadBenchMark",
    data : {rulesetInt: 1},
    success : function(data) {          
             console.log('success');
    },
    error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error Thrown:"  +request.statusText); 
        }
});
```

My struts.xml

```
     <action name="loadBenchMark"
        class="com.test.cashdesk.mktpx.ui.action.LoadDefaultsAction" method="retrieveBenchmark">
        <result type="json"></result>
    </action>
```

I tried my action method to be like

```
  public String retrieveBenchmark(int rulesetInt) {
    // do something here
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

but the call to the action throws a `500 internal server error`.

having a `getter setter` for `rulesetInt` and call to action method like this works. 
`public String retrieveBenchmark() { // access rulesetInt here}` [Answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487978/ajax-post-to-struts2-action-returns-internal-server-error/5488174#5488174)

Please help.

Comment: do Struts2 action methods take parameters? How do I send complex javascript objects to the action. Should I be having a variable called jsonResult with a gettr and setter in the action and .toJSON my javascript object and pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Struts2 action methods do not take arguments. If you want to set a parameter called `rulesetInt`, you will need a `setRulesetInt` method.

**Example**

```
private int rulesetInt;

public String retrieveBenchmark() {
    // do something here
    return SUCCESS;
}

public void setRulesetInt(final int rulesetInt) {
    this.rulesetInt = rulesetInt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send different javascript objects and dont want to declare getter/setter for them in the action class use the following method

In your action class decleration

```
public class YourClass extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware
```

then declare this varible and its getter/setter

```
HttpServletRequest request


public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
}

public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
    return this.request;
}
```

Now in your function

```
public String retrieveBenchmark() {
   String stringValue=getServletRequest().getParameter("rulesetInt");
   int rulesetInt=Integer.parseInt(stringValue);//do this if your value is integer
    // do something here
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

now you can send any variable and without declaring getter function you can access it using  getServletRequest().getParameter("yourVariableName")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I used 'Steven Benitez' way of doing to achieve what I wanted.

I needed to post a lot of complex javascript object arrays as part of ajax call. So now Declared a String variable `ajaxJSONData` in the action with getter and setter.  I put some code below. I deserialize the string on java side.

Ajax call:

```
var postData = ajaxPostData("loadGridData");
// <![CDATA[
$.ajax( {
    type : "POST",
    url : "finalRuleTbaAction",
    data : {"ajaxJSONData" : postData},
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(result) { ............
     });
```

function :

```
function ajaxPostData(callingMethod) {
 if("loadTemplateAndCoupons" == callingMethod) {
    var result = [];
    result.push(new jsObject("ruleset", $('#ruleset').val()));
    result.push(new jsObject("benchmark", $('#productSelect').val()));
    return JSON.stringify(result);
  } else if("loadGridData" == callingMethod) {
    var result = [];
    result.push(new jsObject("ruleset", $('#ruleset').val()));
    result.push(new jsObject("benchmark", $('#productSelect').val()));
    result.push(new jsObject("couponmin", $('#couponmin').val()));
    result.push(new jsObject("couponmax", $('#couponmax').val()));
    return JSON.stringify(result);
  } 
   }
```